# Google Analytics and Angular4+ matrix URL parameters

Tags: angular, google-analytics, angular4-router

In my Angular4+ app, I'm using matrix notation for URL routing params. Google Analytics strips URLs up to first encountered ';'. I found [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11740) but it doesn't help much.

Is there a way to make GA read full URLs like this or my only option is to turn them to queryParams?

Comment: For anyone with same problem: I switched to queryparams.

Comment: Are you using any libraries for sending data to GA? Can you provide a little bit of code to show where you're triggering the ga functions on routing?

Comment: for the bounty: maybe a later answer of the original posters  helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874364/handle-both-url-matrix-query-parameters-in-angular-4

Comment: I switched to queryparams and handle old links using customUrlSerializer. It is a workaround rather than a solution. I'd expect some tweaking in google-analytics configuration to properly fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics has always offered means to force the page path being collected to an explicit value, overriding the default parsing based on location.pathname+location.search

Just set a value for the *page* parameter.

You'll find an example here
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

However, first check which version of the [Google Analytics tracker code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection) you are using, to get the right syntax applicable to that version.
Or prefer to push the value to Google Tag Manager, through a `dataLayer.push('pagePathVariableName','/example-page;field1=value1;field2=value2;field3=value3');` call and do the mapping in GTM

Answer (score 0):

I see here three possible solutions:

1. Write an [URL serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51318210/6276241)
2. Add to the component the ability to parse the URL, detect if it's a matrix notation, and if it is, convert it to query params notation, and redirect to the desired URL. (You could also delegate this work to a [Service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)).
3. Switch to `queryparams` as suggested in the comments.

Comment: I wouldn't say those are solutions but rather workarounds. Imo solution would involve changing configuration of google analytics.

Comment: Yeah, probably, but I don't know if that's possible!